# Request param during file upload is null from iOS with Ionic 2 (beta 11) angular (rc 4) app

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, file-upload

I'm brand new to Ionic and angular.  Currently building a small app to upload a file to our remote server.

The app works correctly when sending a file from an Android device but when we send from an iOS none of the request parameters are getting through to the server.

Here is the relevant code in the app:

```
let options = {
  fileKey: 'photo',
  fileName: queueItem.remoteFileName + '.jpg',
  mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
  chunkedMode: true,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authentication.accessToken,
    'Content-Type': undefined,
  }
  params: {
    "data": { "id": myId, "itemNumber": itemNumber, "contentType": "image/jpeg" }
  }
};

ft.upload(queueItem.filePath, encodeURI(`${this.baseUrl}/photo/uploadPhoto/`), options, true)
     .then((result: any) => {
```

When we do this it works fine from Android devices.  However, iOS devices, the server shows that the request param "data" is null.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: do you have a solution for this ?

Comment: We never really did find a solution...We bypassed it by putting the information we needed to pass in, in the file name and then on the server side we parsed out the info from the file name.  I know it's a bit hackish but it worked until we can find a true answer.

Comment: i'll try that, thank you !